# The Pilgrim in the Pine Forest

Tags: agricola

I just bought the new Agricola ["Gamer's Deck"](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/85704/agricola-gamers-deck) from my local store - hooray!  119 sweet new Occupation / Minor Improvement cards that will keep me happy while I wrestle inwardly with the question of whether I can justify buying the silly-looking "Goodies" expansion for $60, just to scratch my completist's itch.

Looking through the new cards though I found two which seemed to contradict each other.  Can anyone tell me what happens if you get both of these in play?

---

**Pilgrim** (Occupation)

You receive 2 Food before you pay the costs of playing this Occupation.  At the start of a round, if you have no building resources, you may take 1 building resource from the supply; if you have no Food, you may take 1 Food from the supply.  *(At any time, you many move resources from your personal supply to the general supply.)*

---

**Pine Forest** (Minor Improvement)

At the start of each round, you may place 1 Wood on this card if you have zero Wood in your supply.  When this card has 5 Wood, move the Wood from this card to your supply.  (*You may not give Wood to the general supply for nothing.)*

---

If you have both the Pilgrim and the Pine Forest in play, can you "throw away" your spare Wood to keep the Pine Forest growing... or not?  I am particularly confused on this point because both of the relevant lines on the cards are italicized, which gives them the air of being clarifications of the basic rules, rather than special abilities bestowed by the cards.

Does the Pilgrim ruling override the Pine Forest's, or vice versa?  Are you allowed to throw away resources at will in the ordinary course of the rules?  (Not that a sane person would want to, but still...) You can sort of throw away animals you don't have room for... why not resources you don't want?  Anyone think they know the definitive answer?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The definitive answer was given on [BoardGameGeek](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/thread/584170/pilgrim-vs-pine-forest) by Hanno Girke (editor of the rules).

> The Pilgrim has priority.
>
> The Pine Forest just states a standard rule, it doesn't create a new rule.
>
> Therefore, as soon as you play Pilgrim, you override this rule.

There is some background at [play-agricola.com](http://play-agricola.com/forums/index.php?topic=2355.0), where the Gamer's Deck was designed.

As noted by Hanno, the standard rule is on the Pine Forest.  **You may not give goods from your supply to the general supply**.